# complete or completed

Tags: word-difference

Consider a *task* (a computer science term), which can have three states:

- not yet started (queued)
- started (running)
- finished running

What word would be more correct for third state: "complete" or "completed"?

UPD: this word will be used as a table cell value in a column named "state".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Complete* is kind of a tricky word to describe a task, because that word implies that a task can reach a pre-defined end state that meets certain conditions or criteria. But in programming, a task is usually much simpler than that. A task doesn't usually have any end state beyond that it ran OK or didn't run OK. And so I think *completed* -- just meaning "finished" or "done" -- is a better term to describe a task that is done running.

Answer (score 18):

Complete:

> fully constituted of all of its parts or steps, fully carried out, or thorough.

Completed:

> to bring to an end or a perfected status.

Therefore, something is complete, or something has been or was completed.

However, in a lot of cases, you can use either.

In your case, I would use **completed**, to be consistent with the other terms you used (queued, started, finished...), and it sounds better as a standalone word for a state or attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I work in a Software company and the terms we use the most to notify the completion of an ongoing process or task would be:

> - Completed
> - Closed
> - Terminated (Used most often for a bug issue or a problem)
> - Ended/ Concluded (very vague)

Out of which, the most used terms are '**Completed**' and '**Closed**'. For a technical process or a task, we use '**closed**' more commonly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be '**completed**'. Just like '**finished**'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **completed** in a verbal structure, and **complete** as an adjective. Here's a dumb example:

> The task has been **completed**, it is now **complete**.

I can't guarantee you this is the right way to use them though, hoping for some feedback.

Comment: This word won't be used in a sentence, it will be used as a table cell value.

Comment: In this case, I think "completed" as "having gone through the process of completion" makes sense, but I don't see "complete" being wrong either. Next to "not yet started" and "started", I would definitely use "completed".

Answer (score 0):

In the context, they both are quite similar in meaning. However, the adjective "complete" refers to a state of completeness, whereas passive form of the verb "to complete" suggests a finished action/process.  Since the state of the task is a finished/completed process, I would, too, use "completed".

Answer (score 0):

Complete is a state of being; there is nothing that can be added or changed. Whereas completed is an act of completion - the task that was set has now been fulfilled. For example "The Bible is complete and has been completed".

Comment: I don't know if that's a distinction in a dictionary, but in general usage people will describe as task as complete once it has been done.