# "Transfer complete", "transfer is complete" or "transfer is completed" - difference?

Tags: meaning

While "transfer is complete" and "transfer is completed" are more or less clear for me, I can't understand what "Transfer complete" means against other phrases. What part of speech `complete` belongs in "Transfer complete"? Why it is used without `is`?

Comment: "Transfer complete" is just "headlinese" - ungrammatical short forms used to save space, in headlines, electronic status messages, road signs, etc.

Comment: ...for the other two, see [complete or completed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90801/complete-or-completed)

Comment: Although most answers on that earlier question favour ***completed***, I think it's a slightly different context. I'd prefer ***complete*** (with no verb) in your context. Not just because it's one letter shorter, although that could be a factor in why it's more common (not that I'm able to easily *prove* that, but I'm pretty sure the shorter version *will* be more common as a computer-generated status message). I'd compare it to, say, *Tank full* as opposed to *Tank filled* in a car fuel tank status message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> Transfer complete

is just a shortened form of

> Transfer is completed
>   Transfer is finished

and could just as easily have been

> Transfer done

without loss of meaning.