# Why there is no "is" in "Internal storage running out"?

Tags: ellipsis

I had this notification in my phone: "Internal storage running out".

Wonder what the grammar rule allows to omit "is" in such sentences? I would like to read more about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Transfer complete", "transfer is complete" or "transfer is completed" - difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95770/transfer-complete-transfer-is-complete-or-transfer-is-completed-differe) Things like computer status messages and newspaper headlines aren't constrained by standard grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain kinds of text do not have to obey the ordinary rules of grammar when brevity is important. These include road signs, warning notices, text messages, newspaper headlines, and, as here, computer error and warning messages. Words are omitted if they are not essential for understanding.

Comment: And “to be” in particular is unusually likely to be removed.